# Python Requests: how to GET and POST a picture without saving to drive?

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

The API I'm working on has a method to send images by POSTing to `/api/pictures/` with the picture file in the request.

I want to automate some sample images with Python's requests library, but I'm not exactly sure how to do it. I have a list of URLs that point to images.

```
rv = requests.get('http://api.randomuser.me')
resp = rv.json()
picture_href = resp['results'][0]['user']['picture']['thumbnail']
rv = requests.get(picture_href)
resp = rv.content
rv = requests.post(prefix + '/api/pictures/', data = resp)
```

`rv.content` returns bytecode. I get a 400 Bad Request from the server but no error message. I believe I'm either 'getting' the picture wrong when I do `rv.content` or sending it wrong with `data = resp`. Am I on the right track? How do I send files?

**--Edit--**

I changed the last line to

```
rv = requests.post('myapp.com' + '/api/pictures/', files = {'file': resp})
```

Server-side code (Flask):

```
file = request.files['file'] 
if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
    ...
else:
    abort(400, message = 'Picture must exist and be either png, jpg, or jpeg')
```

Server aborts with status code 400 and the message above. I also tried reading `resp` with BytesIO, didn't help.

Comment: What is the content of `prefix`? how is it handling the payload? Are you expecting a file-like object?

Comment: `rv.content` is correct. I ran `open('/tmp/foo', 'wb').write(rv.content)` and got a valid JPG of some random person's avi.

Comment: Read the API docs for `prefix`. You likely need to specify the Content-Type of the data you're uploading.

Comment: Check out help() on requests.get, requests.post and requests.request.

Then study up on file-like objects, EG:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html
https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html

Comment: prefix is just a variable that I made that is the root of my application. @dstromberg, I will check that out, I need to learn the difference between files and file-like objects.

Comment: Without seeing the code which handles the actual POST request within your webserver, there's no way we could tell you what's wrong here. As others have said, rv.content does in fact contain a valid binary image, so we'll need more code to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your data is not a file, its a stream of bytes. So it does not have a "filename" and I suspect that is why your server code is failing.

Try sending a valid filename along with the correct mime type with your request:

```
files = {'file': ('user.gif', resp, 'image/gif', {'Expires': '0'})}
rv = requests.post('myapp.com' + '/api/pictures/', files = files)
```

You can use [`imghdr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imghdr.html) to figure out what kind of image you are dealing with (to get the correct mime type):

```
import imghdr

image_type = imghdr.what(None, resp)
# You should improve this logic, by possibly creating a
# dictionary lookup
mime_type = 'image/{}'.format(image_type)
```

Comment: I just figured this out as you posted it. It was on the requests docs (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file). Thank you!